# How to save an object to db and connect it with logged in user

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I'm making my first web-app using Spring Boot, Thymeleaf, Hibernate (with in-memory H2 database). I also want to use **Spring Security** but I try to avoid it for now (want to finish Entities and repositories first although I know I will have to change the way they work) I want a user to register on my site (he is created and added to my db) and then he can CRUD his ToDos (which are also saved to db). I have connected both entitites with bidirectional OneToMany using annotations and @JoinTable/@mappedBy. Here are my entities:

**ToDoItem.java**

```
@Entity
@Table (name = "TO_DO_ITEM")
public class ToDoItem extends BaseEntity {


@Column(name = "TITLE", nullable = false)
private String title;

@Column(name = "COMPLETED")
private boolean completed;

// TODO: 29.01.17 Add description property

@Column(name = "DUE_DATE", nullable = false)
private LocalDate dueDate;

// two-directional OneToMany
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID")
private User user;


// JPA demands empty contructor
ToDoItem() {}

public ToDoItem(String title, LocalDate dueDate) {
    this.title = title;
    this.dueDate = dueDate;
}


public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public boolean isCompleted() {
    return completed;
}

public void setCompleted(boolean completed) {
    this.completed = completed;
}

public LocalDate getDueDate() {
    return dueDate;
}

public void setDueDate(LocalDate dueDate) {
    this.dueDate = dueDate;
}


public User getUser() {
    return user;
}

public void setUser(User user) {
    this.user = user;
}

}
```

**User.java**

```
@Entity
@Table (name = "USERS")
public class User extends BaseEntity {

@Column(name = "USERNAME")
private String username;

// TODO: 28.01.17 Find a way to store hashed and salted pws in DB
@Column(name = "PASSWORD")
private String password;

@Column(name = "EMAIL")
private String email;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
private Set<ToDoItem> toDoItems = new HashSet<>();

// JPA demands empty constructor
User() {}

public User(String username, String password, String email) {
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
    this.email = email;
}

public Set<ToDoItem> getToDoItems() {
    return toDoItems;
}

public void setToDoItems(Set<ToDoItem> toDoItems) {
    this.toDoItems = toDoItems;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

}
```

I am initialized a set in User.java so I can add created items by logged in user to his own set so they are not just sent to the db, but they are actually connected. Now I just need a method to add newly created item by him to his set (and to the db).

I have two Service beans:
**ToDoItemServiceBean.java**

```
@Service
public class ToDoItemServiceBean implements ToDoItemService {

@Autowired
private ToDoItemRepository toDoItemRepository;

@Override
public Iterable<ToDoItem> listAllToDoItems() {
    return toDoItemRepository.findAll();
}

@Override
public ToDoItem getToDoItemById(Long id) {
    return toDoItemRepository.findOne(id);
}

@Override
public ToDoItem addNewToDo(ToDoItem toDoItem) {
    return toDoItemRepository.save(toDoItem);
}

@Override
public void deleteToDo(Long id) {
    toDoItemRepository.delete(id);
}
}
```

**UserServiceBean.java**

```
@Service
public class UserServiceBean implements UserService {

@Autowired
private UserRepository userRepository;

@Override
public User saveUser(User user) {
    return userRepository.save(user);
}
}
```

And I have no clue how to add those ToDos to a specific user in db. Should I just add an item to a set in addNewToDo so apart from adding new ToDo to db this method would also somehow connect ToDo with a user? But how do I do it? What's the best approach to fix it?

[HERE](https://github.com/doublemc/ToDoWebApp) is the rest of my code (didn't want to paste all of my files into this post).

EDIT:
I rethought my db structure and I think that I should have OneToMany in UserEntity because User can have many ToDos but OneToOne in ToDoItemEntity because a ToDo can have only one user - that's correct, right?

And from that link I made something like this, is it ok?

**ToDoItemEntity**

```
// a ToDoItem is only associated with one user
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "toDoItems")
private User user;
```

**UserEntity**

```
//user can have many ToDoItems
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID")
private Set<ToDoItem> toDoItems;
```

Added updateUser to:
**UserServiceBean.java**

```
@Override
public void updateUser(ToDoItem toDoItem) {
    User currentUser = (User) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
    User queriedUser = userRepository.findOne(currentUser.getId());
    queriedUser.setToDoItems();
}
```

Comment: One user can have many todo items and many todoitems belongs to a user so it is one to many and many to one . it is upto you to decide whether it is birectional or unidriectional . so change Onetoone to ManyToOne

Answer (score 0):

you can add ToDoItems to the user and save the user entity. Make use of **Cascade operations** to cascade the operation

http://howtodoinjava.com/hibernate/hibernate-jpa-cascade-types/

```
// two-directional OneToMany
@ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID")
private User user;
```

update : **UserServiceBean.java**

```
public void updateUser(User user){
   // update the user entity here by adding the todoitems and call saveuser again
}
```

Update 2 : **ToDoItemController**

```
 @Override
    public ToDoItem addNewToDo(ToDoItem toDoItem) {
        return toDoItemRepository.updateItems(toDoItem);
    }
```

ToDoItemServiceBean :

```
public void updateItems(ToDoItem toDoItem) {
    User currentUser = (User) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
    User queriedUser = userRepository.findOne(currentUser.getId());
   toDoItem.setUser(queriedUser);
  saveToDoItem(toDoItem)// since it is bidirectional 

}
```

Comment: I edited my post above - could you check if that makes sense?

Comment: What about that Set initialization? Don't I need some method to add ToDos to that set so a sepcific user is truly connected with his ToDos?? Or it's redundant and whenever a user logs in and adds some ToDos set cascades will automatically connect his todos with him?

Comment: no need to initialize Set here. keep adding todoitems to the user and save the user entity or vice versa.

Comment: Where would u put that addition - in what method in my Service Beans? I posted them above. Sorry for stupid questions but I'm new to this and it kinda overwhelms me - especially working with db.

Comment: it depends. See if you are adding the user with todoitems for the first time you can have a constructor accordingly .. or else simply get the user from repository and iave the user entity again y settting the todoitems in a method and call save again

Comment: First of all I'm getting an error when I use the code with cascades - edited my top post with exception. Can u check that? ANd then I'll try to fix updatingUser issue

Comment: i already commented out. use OneToMany not onetoOne . please read the comment made above in the direct post

Comment: Alright, that fixed it. But still I don't know how to implement updateUser method. How do I know which ToDo to add?

Comment: logged in user can be obtained through the principal incase you are using spring security or else you should get the user logged in and get the user entity by querying against the db and add the todo items to the user and save it ?

Comment: Added method above - how should I add the todoItem to the set if I don't have Set anywhere in that class? Also where would I use this command? In my Controller?

Comment: Are u sure u meant ToDoItemController in your 2nd edit? I don't know how I could use that in there.

Comment: yes .I saw your code . you are adding a todoitem in todocontroller then you have to manipulate in to do only but you can still invoke userservicebean inside todocontrolller. its upto you .either way cascading should work